# saving xml data to mongodb as json

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am looking to save data into mongodb as the given format in picture.
I have xml data in txt file, i have converted it to json using xml2json package. But when i try to save it into db it saves like a string.
But i want it to be saved as json.

below is my code

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/files");

 var db = mongoose.connection;

 db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error"));
 db.once("open", function(callback) {
     console.log("Connection succeeded.");
});


var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./abc.txt', 'utf8');

var result = convert.xml2json(xml,{compact: true, spaces: 4});


 db.collection('files').insert({result}, function(error, record){
 if (error) throw error;
 console.log("data saved");
  });
```

[Like this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2rHq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you have is a JSON string, so it will be stored as a string.

Try to use `JSON.parse` and save the Javascript object.
Just a thought... 
HTH

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js says:

> To convert XML text to JavaScript object, use `xml2js()`. To convert XML text to JSON text, use `xml2json()`.

So it looks like silverfighter is correct: you can fix it with `JSON.parse`. Or you could just use `convert.xml2js` instead. (Either way, `spaces: 4` will have no effect.)

I imagine you'll need to do some more processing to get a javascript object in the format mongoose accepts. But you haven't told us the format of the xml file, and in any case I don't know mongoose, so I can't help with that part.